# Retrieve public key and check the signature with web3

Tags: transactions, signature, public-key

I create a transaction with [signTransaction](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html?highlight=signTransaction#signtransaction)
and I have an output like this:

```
"signedTx": {
    "messageHash": "0x..",
    "v": "0x..",
    "r": "0x..",
    "s": "0x..",
    "rawTransaction": "0x....."
},
```

Now I want to retrieve public key using v r and s And verify the signature

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ecRecover` function in web3@1.0.0

```
web3.eth.personal.ecRecover(dataThatWasSigned, signature [, callback])
```

**Example**

```
web3.eth.personal.ecRecover("Hello world", "0x30755ed65396facf86c53e6217c52b4daebe72aa4941d89635409de4c9c7f9466d4e9aaec7977f05e923889b33c0d0dd27d7226b6e6f56ce737465c5cfd04be400").then(console.log);
```

> "0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe"

Or you can use `ethereumjs-utils` library function [ecrecover](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util/blob/master/docs/index.md#ecrecover)

**Edit**
You can use this to recover public address

```
const publicKey = util.ecrecover(util.sha3('test'), sig.v, sig.r, sig.s);
const address = util.pubToAddress(publicKey).toString('hex');
```